# Django migration delete and update

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have already had some migration files, and I made some changes in the model and did

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

After that in postgresql table django_migrations there is a row indicating I've applied that migration, let's call this migrationA.
I deleted the new generated migration file (migrationA), modified a small piece in my model and then did

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

This generate migrationB. I was hoping this can do the same as squashing migration files.

Will this kind of flow cause any trouble? I didn't see any trouble now but want to make sure this is a safe way to do things. In addition, is there any way to revert postgresql to the time before I applied migrationA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will cause trouble. All the migrations are stored in the migrations table and just deleting a migration will produce inconsistencies between your actual migrations and what's recorded.

Before deleting a migration and creating a new one, you need to first revert it by running `./manage.py migrate my_app number_previous_migration_name`.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can fix it for now? I've already deleted the migrationA file.

Comment: You can try to reset the migrations back, using `--fake` flag or alternatively remove the ones you deleted from `django_migrations` table in your db.

Comment: When deleting from django_migrations table, does it only delete the history record for applying a migration, or also removes the effect of that applied migration?

Comment: The record only, you can see the migration list by running `./manage.py showmigrations`

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but then why will remove migrationA record from ```django_migrations```table be a fix?

Comment: Because when you run those migrations in another env (staging, etc) the app won't be looking for missing migrations. One more thing you can do is to revert all migrations with `./manage.py app_name zero`, and using `--fake` flag for migrations that are missing, however be advise that it will also remove all the from the db for that app.