# How to delete 0001_initial.py in Django? Django migrations are not working

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am using Django 2.2 with Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

I created a project and then an app.  The models.py was populated by using INSPECTDB for an existing Postgres database.  I removed the line 'managed = False' from each class.

I created the initial makemigrations and did the migrate.  There are app migration files, 0001_initial.py and **init**.py

I had to make changes, adding more classes, in the models.py file.  Then I ran the makemigration and migrate on the app.

Now I get a message '.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "INT_ORG" already exists.'  Throws an exception.

I tried to use 'python manage.py makemigrations' and got the message that there were no changes detected.

I tried to use 'python manage.py migrate --fake-initial'.  This
Errored with duplicate table already exists

No luck.  I'm failing badly here.

And while working yesterday, somehow - don't know how, another migration file shows up called '0002_auto_20191212_1137.py'  The '0002_auto_20191212_1137.py' migration file has all my changes in it.  But it is not being migrated either when I try to makemigrations and migrate.

I need to go back to a point I can understand and not loose everything.  A co-worker had a similar problem and they just started a new project and new app.  I don't want to have to do that.

Can someone please tell me how to delete the migration files: 0001_initial.py and 0002_auto_20191212_1137.py  ?
I would like to do this in the terminal window of PyCharm for Django.

I have tried this code to remove migrations:
'delete from django_migrations where app = myapp'
and got the error:
'delete' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have tried this code to remove migrations:
'git rm myapp/migrations/*'
and got the error:
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have tried this code to remove migrations:
'remove myapp/migrations/*'
and got the error:
'remove' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have looked at several sources on the internet and also in StackOverflow that are similiar to my problem, but no answers that work.

Would appreciate any help.  Thank you.
Mag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered here, you should revert back to the point that you want: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57417496/11338792) Hope that's the answer which you're looking for!

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I am considering the content.  However, let me ask...How does a migration file get deleted?  The author of that article said they deleted the migrationA file.  How?

Comment: Glad that it helped! Well, if you go to your project you should see a directory called `migrations`. Deleting everything inside it except for the `__init.py__` file will delete your migrations.

Comment: Please tell me, exactly, how to delete the migration.  Thank you.

Comment: You should delete the file, like any other file: right click and delete.